# Event Not Firing When Modal Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have created a page with table of tasks. For each task, there is a button that allows the user to complete the task by launching a modal. The form inside the modal is dynamically generated through an ajax call. I'm trying to get the task table to update once the form in the modal is submitted and the modal is hidden. The issue I'm having is that the event is not firing once the modal is hidden. If I put the code to capture the event of the modal being hidden in the form, it does work. But I need the code to be on the page with the task table.

**Task Table (This should update when the modal is hidden)**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    })
</script>
<style>
    table {
        height:70%;
        width:70%;
        padding:50px;
        margin:20px;

    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {

        background-color:#fff;
    }
    table#t01 th    {

        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="_token" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="hidden" name="jobId" id="jobId" value="{{$jobs->id}}">
</form>
<h1>Job #{{ $jobs->id }}</h1><p>
Defendant: {{$jobs->defendant}}<br>
            {{$jobs->street}} @if(!empty($jobs->street2)),&nbsp;{{$jobs->street2}}@endif<br>
            {{$jobs->city}}, &nbsp; {{$jobs->state}}&nbsp; {{$jobs->zipcode}}<p>

{{ link_to("/documents/view/?jobId={$jobs->id}&_token={$token}", 'View Documents') }}&nbsp;  {{link_to("/tasks/service_documents/{$jobs->id}","Download Service Documents",["target"=>"_blank"])}}<p>
<br>

<div id="taskTable"></div>
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Complete Task</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="complete_task">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function task_table() {
        var id = $("#jobId").val();

        $.get("{{ url('api/jobsTable')}}",{id:id},
                function (data) {
                    $('#taskTable').html(data);
                });
    }

    task_table();

    $('.view_data').click(function () {
        var task_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.get("{{ url('tasks/test')}}", { id: task_id },
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#complete_task').html(data);
                    $('#dataModal').modal("show");
                });
    });
    //Should fire but doesn't
    $('#dataModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        task_table();
    });


});
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Form Loaded Into the Modal**

```
   <html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

   <div>

   Defendant: {{$job->defendant}}<br>
   Address: {{$job->street}}, &nbsp; {{$job->city}}, &nbsp;{{$job-
   >county}},&nbsp; {{$job->state}} &nbsp; {{$job->zipcode}}<br>


   <form id="assign-task">
    {{ Form::label('Assign', 'Assign Server: ') }}
    {{ Form::select('Assign', $vendors, null, ['id' => 'Server']) }}<br>
    <input type="submit">
    <input id="serveeId" name="serveeId" type="hidden" value="{{ $servee->id 
    }}">
    <input id="jobId" name="jobId" type="hidden" value="{{ $job->id }}">
    <input id="taskId" name="taskId" type="hidden" value="{{ $taskId }}">
    <input id="_token" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() 
    }}">

    </form>


    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $("#assign-task").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        var formData = new FormData(this);


        $.ajax({
            url: '/tasks/assign',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#dataModal').modal("hide");


            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        //This fires when the modal is hidden, I only added it here for a 
        test
        $('#dataModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('modal hidden from form');
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: is there any `console.log` error message?

Comment: Where should I put the console.log?

Comment: no need to put, you can right click anywhere on your web and click "inspect element", in "console" tab, is there any message (like an error)?

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot that I was also loading the table through an ajax call and I was loading jquery twice. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that you was also loading the table through an ajax call and you was loading jQuery twice. :-)